# JAXB Validation error - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'codeSystem'. One of '{codeSystem}' is expected

Tags: java, xml, parsing, validation, jaxb

I'm trying to parse and validate XML (jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar), and I'm getting the error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'codeSystem'. One of '{codeSystem}' is expected.

I'm not sure what's causing it, as I think my XML looks correct.

The Schema requirements for codeSystem:

```
<xs:complexType name="GenericPropertyType">
     <xs:element name="codeSystem" type="tns:CodeSystem">
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="code" type="tns:Code">
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="codeText" type="tns:CodeText" minOccurs="0">
     </xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
```

The GenericProperty Java class to which the codeSystem belongs:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GenericPropertyType", propOrder = {
    "codeSystem",
    "code",
    "codeText"
})
public class GenericPropertyType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String codeSystem;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String code;
    @XmlElement
    protected String codeText;

    /**
     * Getters and Setters ommitted.
     * 
     */
}
```

The XML being parsed:

```
<genericProperty>
    <codeSystem>8B-30-33</codeSystem>
    <code>EMAIL_RETRY_COUNT</code>
    <codeText>5</codeText>
</genericProperty>
```

I've tried it with and without providing a namespace in the `genericProperty` and `codeSystem` elements like `xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/context"` but the error remains the same. Any ideas?

***EDIT***
The CodeSystem type in the schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CodeSystem">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Simple Type with Input Restictions</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" fixed="true"/>
  <xs:maxLength value="64" fixed="true"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: How is type CodeSystem defined in the schema?

Comment: Looks nice enough to me. Can you try and validate the document against the schema without using JAXB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by adding this line to the XmlSchema that was being validated against (The XSD file): elementFormDefault="qualified"

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.somedomain.com/context"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.somedomain.com/context"
        **elementFormDefault="qualified"**>
```

I had this declared in my package-info.java class, but it slipped my mind to check if it was in the XSD schema supplied to the JAXB parser.